# Question about $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin{(k)}\tan (1/k)}{\sqrt{k}}.$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

This is an alternating series because of $\sin{k}$. But if there is no $\pi/2$ in the argument for $\sin$, can I still replace $\sin{k}$ with $(-1)^k$? I don't think so.

Here is what I tried instead; the triangle inequality gives

$$\left|\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin{(k)}\tan (1/k)}{\sqrt{k}}\right|\leq\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left|\frac{\sin{(k)}\tan (1/k)}{\sqrt{k}}\right|=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{|\sin{(k)}|\tan (1/k)}{\sqrt{k}}.$$

I dont really know how to proceed and if this even makes sense because the triangle inequality applied like this requires that the series is absolutely convergent, and I've not shown that.

Comment: For an alternating series, successive terms should have opposite signs *always*, not just *quite often*.

Comment: This is not alternating.  Alternating needs to switch between positive and negative every term.

Comment: You can apply the absolute value like this.  The only possible problem is if the series on the right diverges, it doesn't tell you anything about the convergence of the left.

Comment: Hints: what is the largest that $|\sin(k)|$ can be?  Can you relate $\tan(x)$ to $x$ using an inequality for small $x$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It ought to converge absolutely. Note that $\tan(1/k)\sim 1/k$ for large $k$.

So you have
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left|\frac{\sin(k)}{\sqrt{k}}\tan(1/k)\right|=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{|\sin(k)|}{\sqrt{k}}\tan(1/k)\leq\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\tan(1/k)\sim\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^{-3/2}
$$
convergent by the p test.

Comment: Thanks man. How does one in words say $\sim$ ? Does this mean "asymptotically equal to"?

Comment: yes that would be fine

Comment: But doesn't the application of the triangle inequality require the series to be absolutely convergent? I've not show that yet but still using it.

Comment: yes, in fact you have shown that the series is absolutely convergent

Comment: So, I' first assuming that it's absolutely convergent, then applying the triangle inequality? Say that the result was divergent, what can be concluded from that, about the series?

Comment: we at no point assumed it was absolutely convergent. We bounded the absolute value of the terms in the series by something convergent. If you like names, this shows that the $\sum_n |a_n|$ converges by the comparison test

Answer (score 3):

*Hint:* We have $|\sin x|\le 1$, and for small $x$ we have $\tan x\approx x$.

Comment: ugh, beat me to it

Comment: Damn, it's ridicolous how simple you guys make it. Thanks!

Comment: if you see a function with a known taylor series with an argument getting small you should first "see" it's taylor expansion

Comment: What do you mean?